# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Powershell script -Run as Admin - fails in Task Scheduler A constraint violation occurred

Tags: powershell, active-directory, scheduled-tasks

This script work when starting manualy by double click, or from powershell console not started as administrator. This script requires admin privileges. Script checks if if user account inheritance is disabled (Security-Advanced) and if yes, enables it.

```
#### START ELEVATE TO ADMIN #####
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$shouldAssumeToBeElevated,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$workingDirOverride
)

# If parameter is not set, we are propably in non-admin execution. We set it to the current working directory so that
#  the working directory of the elevated execution of this script is the current working directory
if(-not($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('workingDirOverride')))
{
   $workingDirOverride = (Get-Location).Path
}

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

# If we are in a non-admin execution. Execute this script as admin
if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($shouldAssumeToBeElevated) {
        Write-Output "Elevating did not work :("

    } else {
        #                                                         vvvvv add `-noexit` here for better debugging vvvvv 
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -file "{0}" -shouldAssumeToBeElevated -workingDirOverride "{1}"' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition, "$workingDirOverride"))
    }
    #exit
}

#Set-Location "$workingDirOverride"
##### END ELEVATE TO ADMIN #####

# Add actual commands to be executed in elevated mode here:
Write-Output "I get executed in an admin PowerShell"



    # Error handling
    Function Exception {
         $err = $_.Exception.Message
         write-output $err | timestamp >> $LogFile
         return $err  
     }
    
     # Create logs directory and file if not exist
    $LogFile = "C:\gpo\inheritance.log"
    filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}
      
    If (-not(Test-Path -Path $LogFile)){
        New-Item -Path $LogFile -ItemType File -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    
    
    # Truncate log file
      
    # Get number of lines of log file
    $logfileLines = Get-content $LogFile | Measure-Object –Line | select -ExpandProperty Lines
    if($logfileLines -gt '5000') {
        (Get-Content $LogFile | Select-Object -Skip 4000) | Out-File $LogFile
      }
      
    
    
    $users = Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(objectclass=user)" -searchbase "OU=something.local,DC=example,DC=local"
    
    ForEach($user in $users)
    {
        Try{
            $dn= [ADSI](“LDAP://” + $user)
            $acl= $dn.psbase.objectSecurity
            if ($acl.get_AreAccessRulesProtected()){
                $isProtected = $false # $false to enable inheritance
                                 # $true to disable inheritance
                $preserveInheritance = $true # $true to keep inherited access rules
                                         # $false to remove inherited access rules.
                                         # ignored if isProtected=$false
                $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($isProtected, $preserveInheritance)
                $dn.psbase.commitchanges()
                $output = ($user.SamAccountName + "|" + `
                        $user.DistinguishedName + `
                        "|inheritance set to enabled")
                write-output $output | timestamp >> $LogFile
              }
             }
          Catch{
               Exception
           }
        }
```

However, it fails from Task Scheduler, somehow it's not running with Admin privileges, user account specified in Task scheduler is domain admin.
Run with highest privileges - checked

Prorgram/script:`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
Add arguments (optional):`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\GPO\enable-inheritance.ps1"`
Start in (Optional):`C:\GPO`

Tried putting powershell into bat script, again, works manually but not via Scheduler

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\GPO\inheritance.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Script is running on Domain controller, added "Log on as batch job rigts

Error when running through scheduled task:

```
Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation occurred.
```

No error when running manually

Comment: Did you start powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin?  A normal user cannot upgrade to Admin.  If you start powershell as a normal user you cannot upgrade to admin inside the script.

Comment: as i wrote, user running the task is domain administrator

Comment: Powershell does not run as Admin (even if you login as Admin) unless you right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: tried, same error

Comment: What account is Task Scheduler using?  Does account contain an environmental?  A script can fail if it doesn't have PSModulePath.

Comment: What account is the scheduler using?  When you schedule a task you can add parameter to Run As.

Comment: already did it, in run as domain admin account is specified

Comment: I suspect it running different versions of cmdlets.  Powershell look for cmdlets in current folder and if doesn't find then it checks the PSModulePath.  Do you get any output from script when run normal?  The outputs may be causing task to fail.  See : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/powershell-information-message-will-cause-the-pipe/783880

Comment: yes,output is redicrected to log file which is populated when script runs normaly and when running through task, then only following is written to log, it's error in Catch block:`Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation occurred.`

Comment: Maybe it is a managedby attribute missing like in this posting : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1c9081b5-973d-4da7-8354-aa609d720fa7/powershell-error-quota-constraint-violation-occurredquot-on-setinfo?forum=winserverpowershell&force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by disabling UAC and rebooting server